# Issues with totaling separate sums with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having issues with my javascript code.  I am attempting to have separate sums for each "Retail", "Treatments", "New Clients" and "Retention". When I mess around with the classes adding ".txt, .txt2, etc" it still only sums in the top field.

Here's the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".txt, .txt2, .txt3, .txt4").each(function() {
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateSum();
        });
    });
});

function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".txt, .txt2, .txt3, .txt4").each(function() {
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });
    $("#sum").val(sum);
}
```

Here's a link to the app http://jsfiddle.net/veL6K/

I will try and clarify if this does not make sense.

Comment: What the snippet above is doing is basically take all the values in all fields with the classes .txt, .txt2, .txt3, .txt4, add them all up together, and put the answer into the field with the ID #sum, which is exactly the same as the "problem" which you're describing. You have a logic error here, you'll need to rewrite your calculateSum function so it does what you want it to do correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".txt, .txt2, .txt3, .txt4").each(function() {
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateSum($(this).attr("class")); // passing current class name to the function
        });
    });
});

function calculateSum(cls) {
    var sum = 0;
    $("." + cls).each(function() { // here specifying current class name
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });
    $("#sum" + cls.substr(3,4)).val(sum); // based on class name changing result id
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ch94X/1/) Check it out

**NOTE:** You were just specifying one current `txt` field and one current `sum` (result) id, you should do like I've posted

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest starting from scratch. Your markup is a bit messy and jsfiddle shows a few errors. I'd start with a simple table and go from there.

Take this markup:

```
<table class="table-sum" border="1">
  <tr><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th><th>D</th><th>Result</th></tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="qty" type="text"></td>
    <td><input class="qty" type="text"></td>
    <td><input class="qty" type="text"></td>
    <td><input class="qty" type="text"></td>
    <td><input class="result" type="text" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="qty" type="text"></td>
    <td><input class="qty" type="text"></td>
    <td><input class="qty" type="text"></td>
    <td><input class="qty" type="text"></td>
    <td><input class="result" type="text" disabled></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You only need one class for quantity inputs and one class for result inputs. That's the purpose of classes, reusability.

The JavaScript code is not much to handle this logic. Using jQuery we find the elements needed in relation to the current element, calculate the sum and update the result:

```
function calculateSum() {
  var $cells = $(this).parent().siblings();
  var $inputs = $cells.find('.qty').add(this);
  var sum = $inputs.toArray().reduce(function(a,e) {
    return a + Number(e.value);
  }, 0);
  if (!isNaN(sum)) {
    $cells.find('.result').val(sum);
  }
}

$('.qty').keyup(calculateSum);
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/tatigevi/2/edit

Comment: Yeah, that actually looks a lot cleaner then what I have. Thank you!